# Unsymmetrical map marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a map marker like this:

[image]

Now because the arrow located on its side when I zoom the map it seems like the location changes.
Is there a way to fix that? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `MarkerOptions` you would use the [anchor](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#anchor(float,%20float)) method to adjust where the marker is positioned